# Select all users from subgroups in T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table that holds groups and subgroups that I am using to define user permissions in application. What I am trying to accomplish is to select all users ids from all subgroups based on used id assigned to group.

[image: SQL Server data]

I have tried with this query but it only shows one level of subgroup users.

```
SET @UserIds =
    ISNULL(
        STUFF((SELECT ',' + CAST(tbl.UserID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
               FROM 
                   (SELECT grpUser.UserId AS UserID
                    FROM dbo.GroupUser grpUser
                    INNER JOIN (SELECT subGrp.Id, subGrp.GroupName
                                FROM dbo.Groups grp
                                INNER JOIN dbo.GroupUser guser ON grp.Id = guser.GroupId
                                                               AND guser.UserId = @UserId
                                INNER JOIN dbo.Groups subGrp ON grp.Id = subGrp.ParentGroupId) tbl ON grpUser.GroupId = tbl.Id) AS tbl
                FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ''), '')
```

I am struggling to get users ids in all subgroups. Number of subgroups is not defined. Is there a way to do in sql or should I shift this part to application side? Thank you for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I came up with this code. Thank you for hint.

```
declare @UserGroupId int;
       Set @UserGroupId = (Select GroupId from GroupUser gu 
                          left join dbo.Groups gr on gu.GroupId = gr.id
                          where UserId = @UserId and gr.IsDeleted = 0)

       declare @UsersGroups  Table (
       Id int not null,
       GroupName nvarchar(50) not null
        )

        ;WITH grp AS
        (
            SELECT Id, GroupName

            FROM Groups
            WHERE ParentGroupId = 1
            UNION ALL
            SELECT g.Id, g.GroupName
            FROM Groups g
            INNER JOIN dbo.GroupUser guser ON g.Id = guser.GroupId
            INNER JOIN grp ON g.ParentGroupId = grp.Id  
        )

        Insert into @UsersGroups    
        SELECT Id, GroupName
        FROM grp

        SET @UserIds =  ISNULL(STUFF(( SELECT   ',' + CAST(tbl.UserID AS VARCHAR(max)) FROM ( 
                            SELECT grpUser.UserId AS UserID FROM    dbo.GroupUser grpUser
                            INNER   JOIN ( SELECT * FROM @UsersGroups
                            ) tbl ON grpUser.GroupId = tbl.Id
                            ) AS tbl FOR XML PATH('') ), 1, 1, ''), '')
```